# How to sum all n-th rows of arrays in array (numpy)?

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have the array:

```
 import numpy as np
 a = np.array([[[1], [3], [5]], [[2], [8], [6]]]
```

How can I sum all first rows together, all second rows together and so so? So, I the result I want is something like this

```
 [3, 11, 11] or [[3], [11], [11]]
```

It seems to be so simple but I can't find solution which doesn't require loops...

Comment: Last one - `11`? `a.sum(0)`?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is [np.sum](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) where you sum over the `0th` axis.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[[1], [3], [5]], [[2], [8], [6]]])
b = a.sum(0)
# b = array([[3],[11],[11]])
```

Though your initial addition was off `1 + 2 = 3`, `3 + 8 = 11`, and `5 + 6 = 11` leaves us with `3, 11, 11`

Alternatively, as NAN pointed out

```
np.sum(a, axis=(0,2))
# array([ 3, 11, 11])
```

Comment: or np.sum(a, axis=(0,2))  if you just want it like array([ 3, 11, 11])